# Instagram Gem and Faraday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having an issues with the instagram gem, I don't know where these issues came from, but everything was working fine until I performed a bundle update. Here's the issue:

If I use `gem 'instagram'` in my gemfile, I get the error:

```
undefined method `configure' for Instagram:Module
```

I then read online and found a solution to this issue is to add the github path like `gem "instagram", :git => 'git://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem.git'` but then I get the error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":
  In Gemfile:
    instagram (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (< 0.9, >= 0.7) ruby

    omniauth-facebook (>= 0) ruby depends on
      faraday (0.9.0)
```

I tried manually editing the gem to use faraday 0.9.0, but it causes additional problems. Any ideas how to fix this issue and get the instagram gem working again? (it was working before, no idea what messed it up!)

Comment: remove the **Gemfile.lock** and then issue `bundle install`, and show the errors if any.

Comment: tried that, the errors i got are listed above. solved the problem by explicitly stating that rails should use faraday ~> 0.8.9

Answer (score 3):

Solved by putting `gem "faraday", "~> 0.8.9"` in my gem file, forcing it to use the old version

Comment: I'm trying to do this but Twitter gem requires faraday > 0.9. Can't win.

Comment: Having the same issue as @Dex

Comment: bundle update instead of bundle install did it for me! ;)